# How to make context menu item to many files?

Tags: c#, registry, contextmenu

I make context menu item for images(for example), it should open my console application, using target file as string argument. When I use it for many files it opens many application copies, and for each one it has one string argument, but I want to send array of string to one application.

As I researched, it is impossible on registry level, so my application should search for it's copies and get their string arguments. How to realize it in c# console application?